# Magento 1.9.3.7 not sending emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, magento1.9.3.7

I am using `Magento 1.9.3.7` at URL http://wowitprojects.com/inkmytale/
But i did not get any emails. I have already make changes suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27450413/magento-1-9-1-0-order-confirmation-emails-not-sending.

Comment: How do you know it's not sending? if you went through all the steps in that post, then I suggest you check your spam folder

Comment: I am getting "order confirmation mail not send" in admin order detail. i have checked in spam also and stuck in this since morning..while my server is sending by phpmailer script but magento does not....

Comment: can you send me a screenshot of your oder, where you say it shows email not sent?

Comment: you can check  at http://wowitprojects.com/inkmytale/admin/ username: admin & pass:123456

Comment: never share your credentials like this - anyway they don't work

Comment: See at http://wowitprojects.com/inkmytale/email-error.png

Comment: And what happens when you click on send email?

Comment: When i click send mail i got message "email send."

Comment: and? did you get the email?

Comment: no, i didn't get any mail.

Comment: Can you tell me what you have set for `system=>Configuration=>Advanced=>System=>Mail Sending Settings=>Disbale Email Communications`

Comment: Disable Email Communications: No 
Host:localhost 
Port (25): 25 
Set Return-Path:No

Comment: and you confirmed that the cron is running?

Comment: How i check it?

Comment: look at the answer from Hatef on the post you referenced. you said you went through everything there already but you clearly didnb't